# Combine two lists in R into a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have two lists in R of identical length and would like to combine them into a data frame with the total number of rows in the resulting data frame equivalent to the length of the two lists (in other words, each list is a column). When I tried using `c(list1, list2)` the two lists were appended together and when I used `cbind(list1, list2)` the total number of observations was almost double the original length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
 do.call(rbind.data.frame, Map('c', list1, list2))
```

#### data

```
 list1 <- as.list(1:5)
 list2 <- as.list(6:10)
```

Comment: I used the last piece of code and received an error saying "Error in data.frame(Col1 = unlist(lat_long_zip_key), Col2 = unlist(listing_id)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 57246, 57258" However, when I run the length of the two lists, `length(listing_id) [1] 57258` and `length(lat_long_zip_key) [1] 57258` they appear to have the same length. Any suggestions?

Comment: @g.humpkins I was assuming that your list elements have the same length, but if that is not the case, the `unlist` in both list will return different length.  Can you show a small reproducible example that shows the error?

Comment: Ah, I was able to get it to work with your first code snippet, thanks! Do you have any clue why when I test the length of the lists, they are equivalent, but when I used the `unlist` code they were not?

Comment: @g.humpkins   You are looking at the `length` of the entire list and from your description, both lists have the same length.  But, what if some elements inside that list different in length or nrow etc?  Try to check `sapply(listing_id, length)` or `lengths(listiing_id)` (in R 3.2.0)